# Sencha Architect generated layout can't integrate to Ruby on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm actually working in a Ruby on Rails Project and I've created a simple layout with Sencha Architect and the files Sencha Architect generates are: [image]

and Inside of app folder :

[image]

So I have in my Ruby on Rails project this code for the layout, in te lines 15 and 16 I have already referred to the files that were generated by sencha architect

[image]

And when I run the project the browser console displays this error:

[image]

it can't find the app/view/MainView.js wich indeed is in that rout. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript needs to go in `app/assets/javascripts`.  Just placing the file in `app/view` doesn't make it available at that "route", this is not how Rails works.  You're working with an application, not a static web site serving up all the files in the various directories.

Look into [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), and the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more information.

If you put `MainView.js` into `app/assets/javascripts`, you can include it in the `application.js` file, like the other files that are likely there, or if not, like this:

```
//= require ./MainView     # brings in this one file
```

or

```
//= require_directory .    # brings in all javascripts in the directory
```

And now when you bring in the application javascript, your MainView content will also be included.

Comment: thanks for answer, I place all my Javascripts in assets/javascripts then in the application.js include my javascripts by this way:

//= require ./MainView but the browser console displays :

Comment: Ext is not defined and I have in the layout referenced the libraris of extjs @NickVeys

Comment: Before you bring in the application Javascript?  Usually the last `javascript_include_tag` is the application one, with other things like CDN-hosted scripts before it.